# htaccess (www) not working (no www) is working

Tags: php, .htaccess

No problem once you're without www. gives a 404 error logs in with www

php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('db.php');
$sefurl = mysql_escape_string($_GET['sef']);

if($sefurl==""){

$sefurl =  'homepage' ;

}else{

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page WHERE sefurl='$sefurl'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        switch($data){
        case null;
        echo "<center><h1 style='font-size:500px'>404</h1></center>";
        break;
        default:
        .
        .
        ?>
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([A-Za-z0-9]+).website.com
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?sef=%1  


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Why is giving this error. Does the idea of ​​having

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([A-Za-z0-9]+).website.com
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([A-Za-z0-9]*).website.com
```